# TexDraw doesn't actually draw anything onto the model

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm quite a noob with blender so it probably has something to do with something I haven't ticked, so I'll give as much information as possible.

---

So I've built a very basic building to later export it into a game, I have made the UV and Unwrapped it, but when I'm trying to draw a texture into it by using Tex Draw, the texture doesn't actually get applied:

[image: Trying to draw the texture]

---

I don't know if it has something to do with the shading or what to be honest, here comes my shading settings too:

[image]

---

Here are the settings for the brush too

[image]

[image]

If there's anything I am missing please do let me know and I'll answer as soon as possible, I just really want to start with the texturing as I've been working hard (as hard as you can when you are a beginner really) in this model, thanks :D

Here's the .blend file: [image]

Comment: Hello, maybe pack your images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a *Texture Mask*, and as it is completely black you can't paint anything, you need to remove it:

[image]

Also maybe lower the stencil *Opacity*:

[image]

And make sure the normals are correctly flipped (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]